# Client Validation - Similiar as Gmail and Yahoo

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have seen som different webpage that has a user-friendly validation approach in front end.

For instance when you want to register a new account in gmail or yahoo and if you have  a input box and then you forgot to add last name, a message when display below the input box.

This approach happens only in client mode and you don't need to affect the backend.

I'm fully aware that you need to have validation, both front and backend due to security.

My question is:
Do you know where I can retrieve the source code based on jQuery?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap form validator : http://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator/

jQuery form validator plugin : http://formvalidator.net/

There many form validators on clientside that you can google and find...

I am currently using bootstrap form validator ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of the one specifically used in your example, but one of the most popular and flexible jQuery plugins out there for front end validation is [jQuery Validation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/). It allows you to run callbacks at different validation events and you can write specific rules for each input validation.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of great tutorials for checking if username is taken online. You can choose between making your own system or using a library. I suggest you do it yourself because you can secure it better and customize it's appearance better. Here is a very basic one: http://www.itechroom.com/2010/10/06/username-availability-check-using-php-and-jquery/

For the rest of the field types, you could use a library. There are o lot of thme available. http://jqueryvalidation.org/ is one of them, just like Paul sais. Another one is http://formvalidator.net/#reg-form